# How to copy an Array using Xpath in BPEL

Tags: xpath, esb, wso2, bpel

I have the service response data like below:

```
<Employees>
 <employee>
   <empName>Z</empName>
 </employee>
<employee>
   <empName>Y</empName>
 </employee>
<employee>
   <empName>Z</empName>
 </employee>
 .....
</Employees>
```

Now i wish to copy the same to another BPEL variable in the same structure as below.

```
<EmployeesResponse>
 <employee>
   <empName>Z</empName>
 </employee>
<employee>
   <empName>Y</empName>
 </employee>
<employee>
   <empName>Z</empName>
 </employee>
 .....
</EmployeesResponse>
```

Im not certain about the amount of data i receive and wish to copy all. How can i do that ?

Comment: It isn't clear how your question is related to XSLT. What should be the wanted result from an XSLT solution (we don't know anything about BPEL) ?

Comment: Sorry it was related to xpath

Comment: I don't see the XPath relation.

Comment: i wish to see xpath expression to read out all the array of records and copy to another array in a BPEL with assign activity.

Answer (score 0):

To select all elements from source variable use this query:

```
/Employees/emplyee
```

To copy to your target, use this other query:

```
/EmployeesResponse
```